# K8s coredns and flannel nameserver limit exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, coredns

i have been trying to setup k8s in a single node,everything was installed fine. but when i check the status of my kube-system pods,

**CNI -> flannel** pod has **crashed**, reason ->  Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted, the applied nameserver line is: x.x.x.x x.x.x.x x.x.x.x

**CoreDNS** pods status is **ContainerCreating**.

In My Office, the current server has been configured to have an static ip and when i checked **/etc/resolv.conf**

This is the output

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search ORGDOMAIN.BIZ
nameserver 192.168.1.12
nameserver 192.168.2.137
nameserver 192.168.2.136
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 192.168.1.10
nameserver 192.168.1.11
```

i'm unable to find the root cause, what should i be looking at?

Comment: Rolling back to an older version helped me. Full explanation here: [Github: kube-proxy pods continuously CrashLoopBackOff #118461](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/118461#issuecomment-1974924360)
`sudo apt-get install -y kubelet=1.23.17-00 kubeadm=1.23.17-00 kubectl=1.23.17-00` on Ubuntu LTS 22.04

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short, you have too many entries in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

This is a [known issue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues):

> Some Linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu), use a local DNS resolver by default (systemd-resolved). Systemd-resolved moves and replaces `/etc/resolv.conf` with a stub file that can cause a fatal forwarding loop when resolving names in upstream servers. This can be fixed manually by using kubelet’s `--resolv-conf` flag to point to the correct `resolv.conf` (With `systemd-resolved`, this is `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`). **kubeadm (>= 1.11) automatically detects `systemd-resolved`, and adjusts the kubelet flags accordingly.**

Also

> Linux’s libc is impossibly stuck ([see this bug from 2005](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=168253)) with limits of just 3 DNS  `nameserver`  records and 6 DNS  `search`  records. Kubernetes needs to consume 1  `nameserver`  record and 3  `search`  records. This means that if a local installation already uses 3  `nameserver`s or uses more than 3  `search`es, some of those settings will be lost. As a partial workaround, the node can run  `dnsmasq`  which will provide more  `nameserver`  entries, but not more  `search`  entries. You can also use kubelet’s  `--resolv-conf`  flag.
>
> If you are using Alpine version 3.3 or earlier as your base image, DNS may not work properly owing to a known issue with Alpine. Check  [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30215)  for more information.

You possibly could change that in the Kubernetes code, but I'm not sure about the functionality. As it's set to that value for purpose.

Code can be located [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/c970a46bc1bcc100bbbfabd5c12bd4c5d87f8aea/pkg/apis/core/validation/validation.go#L2944-L2953)

```
const (
    // Limits on various DNS parameters. These are derived from
    // restrictions in Linux libc name resolution handling.
    // Max number of DNS name servers.
    MaxDNSNameservers = 3
    // Max number of domains in search path.
    MaxDNSSearchPaths = 6
    // Max number of characters in search path.
    MaxDNSSearchListChars = 256
)
```

Comment: Note that `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` will be auto-recreated after each k8s restart (is apparently not modifiable despite such errors?)

Comment: No, this is not helpful at all because /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf itself has more than three entries (actually two, but duplicated because of IPv6). So not useful?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but only three entries in my resolv.conf.

> Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted, the applied nameserver line is: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 1.1.1.1

My resolv.conf

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10 
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
options timeout:1
```

But indeed my /run/systemd/resolv/resolv.conf was having redundant DNS.

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1111
nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1001
search .
```

When erasing all 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1, on systemd-resolved service restart, they reappear in double...